# $.ajax(), sometimes, doesn't give a response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've made a "like/dislike" system on my website using `ajax()`. On click the `div` changes his content from `like` to `dislike` and the total likes number, near it, updates.

How sometimes the first AJAX call (like to dislike) works perfectly but the total likes number doesn't. Any ideas? Is it because there are 2 AJAX calls on one click working together? It happens about one time on 20.

Thanks

These are the two span;

```
<span id='like' class='span_like'>Like</span>    
<span id='nlikes'></span>
```

These are the two $.ajax() calls. The first one changes the  content from "like" to "dislike" (or viceversa), and updates the "like" on the database.
The second call counts the total likes number, and reports it in the `<span id='nlikes'></span>`.

```
$('#like').click(function(){  
    var call1 = $.ajax({  
                      url: 'relative_comments_likes_number+1.php',   
                      type: 'GET',  
                      data: {id : '".$loopCMR['id']."'},  
                      dataType: 'text'  
                    });  
                    call1.done(function(data){  
                    $('#like').text(data)}) 

    var call2 = $.ajax({  
                      url: 'comment_likes_number_add_drop.php',   
                      type: 'GET',  
                      data: {value : '".$loopCMR['id']."'},  
                      dataType: 'text'  
                    });  
                    call2.done(function(data){  
                    $('#nlikes').text(data)})  
    })
```

...And these are the two php files

The first call

```
<?php session_start();    
include("DB_connection.php");    

$id=$_GET['id'];  
$liked_q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments_like WHERE    
liked_by='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND id='".$id."'");  
$response=mysql_num_rows($liked_q);  
if($response==0)  
{  
$query=mysql_query("INSERT  
INSERT INTO comments_like(id,liked_by,code)VALUES('".$id."',  
'".$_SESSION['username']."','".$_SESSION['v']."')");  
echo"Unlike";}  

if($response==1)  
{$query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments_like WHERE  
liked_by='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND id='".$id."'");  
echo"Like";}  
?>
```

The second call is...

```
<?php session_start();
include("DB_connection.php");
$id = $_REQUEST['value'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments_like WHERE id='".$id."'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($rows == 0){
echo '';
}else{
echo " (".$rows.")";}
?>
```

So... everything works perfectly.. but occasionally the second call does't works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to do such double calls. Instead do this

```
var loopCMR = "<PHP echo $loopCMR['id']; ?>";    
$('#like').click(function () {
    var call1 = $.ajax({
        url: 'relative_comments_likes_number+1.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: loopCMR },
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#like').text(data);
        var call2 = $.ajax({
            url: 'comment_likes_number_add_drop.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { value: loopCMR },
            dataType: 'text'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#nlikes').text(data)
        });
    });
});
```

or have only ONE php returning both values

Comment: it seems working.. thank you very much... i will also use one php so it should work faster... thanks again..